# Function that returns another function, for a programming task

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, python-3.x

This is a task I was given for an online course. This is my solution to the problem.

Task:
Write a function called `general_poly`, that meets the specifications below.

For example, `general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)` should evaluate to `1234` because

`1*10^3 + 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 4*10^0`

So in the example the function only takes one argument with `general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])` and it returns a function that you can apply to a value, in this case `x = 10` with `general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)`.

```
def general_poly (L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """
    #YOUR CODE HERE
```

My Code:

```
def general_poly (L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """

    def function_generator(L, x):
        k = len(L) - 1
        sum = 0
        for number in L:
            sum += number * x ** k   
            k -= 1
        return sum

    def function(x, l=L):
        return function_generator(l, x)

    return function
```

Comment: Why do you use `L[i]` instead of `number`?

Comment: wow! Facepalm haha i was stressed when i wrote that, thank you very much lol!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The name `function_generator` could be improved. What this function does is to *evaluate* the polynomial at the given value `x`. So a name like `evaluate` would be better.
2. The body of `function_generator` can be simplified. First, it's simpler to iterate over `L` in reversed order, because then you can start with `k = 0` rather than `k = len(L) - 1`:

   ```
   def evaluate(L, x):
       k = 0
       sum = 0
       for number in reversed(L):
           sum += number * x ** k   
           k += 1
       return sum
   ```

   Now that `k` goes upwards, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate the values for `k`:

   ```
   def evaluate(L, x):
       sum = 0
       for k, a in enumerate(reversed(L)):
           sum += a * x ** k
       return sum
   ```

   And now that the body of the loop is a single expression, you can use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function to do the addition:

   ```
   def evaluate(L, x):
       return sum(a * x ** k for k, a in enumerate(reversed(L)))
   ```

   Another approach to polynomial evaluation is to generate the power series in \$x\$ separately:

   ```
   def power_series(x):
       "Generate power series 1, x, x**2, ..."
       y = 1
       while True:
           yield y
           y *= x
   ```

   and then combine it with the coefficients using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

   ```
   def evaluate(L, x):
       "Evaluate the polynomial with coefficients in L at the point x."
       return sum(a * y for a, y in zip(reversed(L), power_series(x)))
   ```

   This is more efficient for large polynomials because each step in `power_series` is a multiplication by `x`, which is cheaper to compute than the exponentiation `x ** k`.

   Finally, you could take advantage of this transformation: $$a_k x^k + a_{k-1} x^{k-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0 = (\cdots ((0 + a_k)x + a_{k-1})x + \cdots + a_1)x + a_0$$ and write:

   ```
   def evaluate(L, x):
       "Evaluate the polynomial with coefficients in L at the point x."
       r = 0
       for a in L:
           r = r * x + a
       return r
   ```

   (This is [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).)
3. There's no need for `function`, because it's fine for the body of `function_generator` to refer to nonlocal variables like `L`. So you can write:

   ```
   def general_poly(L):
       "Return function evaluating the polynomial with coefficients in L."
       def evaluate(x):
           r = 0
           for a in L:
               r = r * x + a
           return r
       return evaluate
   ```
4. An alternative approach is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

   ```
   from functools import partial

   def evaluate(L, x):
       "Evaluate the polynomial with coefficients in L at the point x."
       r = 0
       for a in L:
           r = r * x + a
       return r

   def general_poly(L):
       "Return function evaluating the polynomial with coefficients in L."
       return partial(evaluate, L)
   ```

   This would be useful if you sometimes wanted to call `evaluate` directly (instead of via `general_poly`).